# Modify the size of popup windows in IE9?

Tags: internet, internet-explorer-9, popups

I have a client that uses a web app extensively that utilizes popup windows to display search results. Her problem is that when popups get displayed, they are very small in size and she is forced to resize the window every time.

- I've tried resizing, closing IE9 and all tabs, and reopening.
- Restarting the computer multiple times.
- Upgrading from IE8 to IE9 did not seem to fix this issue either, so I have to believe a fresh install or repair will not fix this problem.
- I am aware of the setting in internet options that allows for popups to be created as new tabs, but she is not fond of that idea and prefers a new popup window.

So my question is, is there some setting that I am missing out on here that will allow me to set how large popup windows are? Hopefully there is a simple solution to this and I am just missing something.

Comment: You can set the size of a popup window with JavaScript.  `window.open` has a `height` and `width` property.  You may need to go in and modify this code.

Comment: Have you access to the server? If so this shoul work: win2 = window.open("win2.html", "Window2", " width=310,height=600,scrollbars=yes");

Answer (score -3):

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append("");
                        sb.Append("window.open('");
                        sb.Append(url);
                        sb.Append("','(What ever page U suse)','height=700,width=1000,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');");
                        sb.Append("");

Comment: Wow! <sarcasm>Great explanation on that answer of yours!</sarcasm> Could you at least tell him what to do with that code.

Comment: The question was asked way before which i never recognized but this for the window or the page which the user is using. It makes the page to resize according to the size mentioned in the height and width.So that the user dont have resize everytime. It worked for me and i did mentioned here

Comment: Where do you put the code??

Comment: You made my day<Sarcasm> This always would go under the popup window function.

Comment: In which file??

Comment: Answers are meant to be written in the thought that this is not just for the question poster but the other users who may be facing similar questions, therefore it would be better if your answer could explain what your code does, where to put etc... in the frame of reference that you are explaining this to a beginner/intermediate level person, also please provide context to the answer to make it more understandable. Thank you.